# Count all category objects in a filtered query in django?

Tags: django, templates, filter, count

I am desperately trying to count the objects in a category in my model. To be more clear: I am scraping news articles and I have this model:

```
class News(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    link = models.CharField(max_length=2083, default="", unique=True)
    published = models.DateTimeField()
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=2083)
    site = models.CharField(max_length=30, default="", blank=True, null=True)
```

and this view filtering objects and serving them upon request:

```
class SearchResultsView(ListView):
    model = News
    template_name = 'search_results.html'
    context_object_name = 'articles'

 
    def get_queryset(self):
        query = self.request.GET.get('q')
        min_dt = self.request.GET.get('qf')
        max_dt = self.request.GET.get('qt')
        object_list = News.objects.filter(Q (title__icontains=query)| 
        Q (desc__icontains=query) & Q (published__range=(min_dt, max_dt))).order_by('-published')
```

I need to put on my html django website how many articles I get for each site

Here is my html

```
 <div class="row">
                        <table>
                            <tbody>
                             <h2>{{ articles.count }} articles found in total </h2>

                      HERE I NEED TO PUT HOW MANY ARTICLES PER SITE BELOW IS 
                      THE ACTUAL LIST ON A TABLE

                                {% for a in articles %}
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <a href="{{ a.link }}">{{ a.title }}</a>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <p>
                                            Source: {{ a.site }}
                                        </p>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <p>
                                            Published: {{ a.published }}
                                        </p>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <p>
                                            More info: {{ a.desc }}
                                        </p>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

In other words I need to Group By Site and Count the results.

THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1):

If for example, the dictionary that you pass your HTML template is as follows;

```
{ articles: object_list }
```

You might need to compute the size of that list and add it to that dictionary as a separate key-value pair and just read pass that along with the `articles` data. There're two methods to do this. You could use the `len()` python function or use the `count()` function that's provided by Django ORM. See the sample below for both methods and their trade-offs.

**Using `len()`**

```
{articles: object_list, number_of_articles: len(object_list)}
```

This method is much more efficient since it avoids hitting that database again as `count()` would. Also, using `len()` is ideal for your scenario because you are fetching the queryset either way.

**Using `count()`**

```
{articles: object_list, number_of_articles: object_list.count()}
```

This is slightly inefficient because the `count()` query will run an extra db query. Use `count()` only if you don't need to process the queryset and all you need is the count ONLY.

In your HTML, therefore, you'll need to get that count like;

```
<h2>{{ number_of_articles }} articles found in total </h2>
```

Comment: Thank you for replying so quickly. I am currently doing a count for ALL objects and I will change it to len as per your suggestion, but my question is how can I get a len (or count) for a GROUP of those objects. In other words group by (category) and count the category results. Thank you again!

Comment: You can then use the Count operation `from django.db.models import Count` and then run your query in the form;

`object_list = News.objects.values('category').annotate(category_count=Count('category')).order_by()`

This will give you a result which is something like:

`object_list = [{"category": "Sports", "category_count": 2}, {"category": "Politics", "category_count": 4}]`